# Probability distribution for a uniform random point in triangle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

$(X,Y)$ is a two dimensional random variable that is uniformly distributed in the triangle : $(0,0),(1,a),(1,b)$ where $0<a<b$,and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.

> Find $f_{X,Y}$(s,t). (The Joint probability distribution of $(X,Y)$).

The solution is:

> Let $T$ be the set of the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ inside that triangle,and let $S$ be the area of that triangle.
>
> So we know that $S= \frac{b-a}{2}$,and that's why $f_{X,Y}(s,t) = \frac{2}{b-a}\chi_T(s,t)$ where $\chi_T(s,t)$ is an indicator that the point $(s,t)$ is in $T$.

But I don't understand the solution.

Comment: How can we understand why you "don't understand,why is that the solution" if you do not say?

Comment: @Did I don't understand why $1/S$ would be the Joint probability distribution?

Comment: Nobody said that 1/S is the joint probability distribution, or any distribution for that matter. 1/S is a **number**, right?

Comment: @Did Yes,it is a number.So how come thats the Joint probability distribution?

Comment: It is not. (Bis.)

Comment: @Did Could you please,explain to me why $f_{X,Y}(s,t)=\frac{2}{b-a}X_T(s,t)$ the Joint probability distribution?

Comment: Sure, as soon as you explain how you think one should compute it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you understand that $S=(b-a)/2$.

Uniform distribution means that the probability density function has the same value everywhere in the triangle, say $f_{X,Y}(s,t)=c$ whenever $(s,t)$ is in the triangle -- i.e., $\chi_T(s,t)=1$. You also know that "probabilities add-up to 1", which in this case translate as:
$$
\iint f_{X,Y}(s,t)\, ds\, dt=\iint c\, \chi_T(s,t)\,ds\,dt=
\int_S c\,ds\,dt=c\,\int_S ds\,dt = c\,S= 1.
$$
Therefore $c=1/S$ and the result follows.